# .js scripts not loading in Colorbox plugin

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate the colorbox lightbox plugin as instructed on there website

I have successfully integrated on one of my pages but i cannot get it to load correctly for the other 3 (in same directory). Onlick it goes to a new page with the full size image on a white background!

An example of this working on my site is here....

http://www.transformyourshape.co.uk/cost-of-Herbalife.php

I have put the exact same scripts, in the exact same places as in this working one on my other page here...

http://www.transformyourshape.co.uk/Herbalife-Weight-Loss.php

But it just won't load the plugin and i have no idea why.

Can anyone see where or why this has gone wrong?

I would appreciate any help, no matter how minor so i can get this resolved

Thanking you all in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add the link to the developers instruction guide i used... http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/

Answer (score 0):

You have included two versions of jquery, which causes $.colorbox to become undefined after second inclusion:

```
<head>
..
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/contactForm/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
</script>
..
..
<!--Colourbox Scripts & CSS -->
<script src="Scripts/js/colourbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/colourbox/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
..
..  
<script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
..
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works perfectly now i have removed the older version from the php include and it works. Thanks for the spot. I have spend many hours trying to get this working so thanks again.